# Databricks SQL analytics

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

am trying to do this tutorial about databricks sql analytics (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/get-started/admin-quickstart) but when i create my databricks workspace i do not have the icon at the bottom of the sidebar to acces SQL analytics (in requirement part).
Can somebody tell me how i can accès to Databricks SQl analytics ?
here is a pic of what i have :
[image]

Comment: As i see you in your link you should  select "Data Science & Engineering" persona ( Step 1: Add a user)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Analytics is in so-called "gated public preview" - you can't enable it yourself.  It's better to contact solution architect from Databricks who work with your company.

Update, November 2021st: Databricks SQL (former SQL Analytics) is no longer in the preview. But it's available only on Premium plan

Comment: Thank you alex, but it was for my own training :D

Comment: then you need to wait until ungated public preview :-) I don't know the time frames although

Answer (score 0):

But still you can try 14 days free trail in any cloud. [link](https://databricks.com/try-databricks?itm_data=demos-try-sqlanalytics-trial)